# Report Builder 3.0 Combing parameter values

Tags: parameters, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I'm adding a prompt to my report that selects records based on Status.  Here are the available values:

Approved = 1

Cancelled = 2

Suspended = 3

Unapproved = 4

The SQL statement in my report uses an IN clause to select the records to return.

My question is that the user would like another option called Non-Cancelled; which would be values 1, 3, and 4.  I assume that I need an expression for the prompt value.  I have tried "1,3,4" and "=(1,3,4)" and "(1,3,4)".  None of these have worked.  I either get errors or no records are returned.

Can I do this.  Any suggestions on the expression I need to make this work would be greatly appreciated.  I can always have a  multiple value parameter and let the user select multiple options but I would rather do it this way if I can.  Thanks for the help.......

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you try <>"2"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  The customer has decided it is alright to use a multi-value parameter.  The end user will have to make multiple selections if they want the non-cancelled items.  Thanks for your help.....